# Why socket.io is not working with Ajax properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, socket.io, emit

For a while i interest nodejs and socket.io. I know i installed nodejs and socket.io properly. I prepared a form then i got values with javascript then by sensing with ajax to my php file, then i got what a want properly. But time to making amit with socket.io i always revieve this. message

```
GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NNbUs8K 404 (Not Found)   polling-xhr.js:203 
GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NNbUsVI 404 (Not Found)   polling-xhr.js:203 
.
.
.
```

Here is my server.js

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);



io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    //console.log('a user connected'); //this works

    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });

  });

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Server.js works properly i tested using this `console.log('a user connected');` and it works well.
Then i tried to emit real datas.
here is my html file making ajax with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-12">

           <form method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwprd">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                </div>
              
                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>

           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

    

   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>


        $(function () {
            $("#submit").on("click",function(){

                var dataString = { 
                    email : $("#email").val(),
                    password : $("#password").val(),
                };

                $.post("isle.php",{data:dataString},function(response){


                    // console.log(response);
                    var socket = io();

                    socket.emit('chat message', dataString);
                    return false;

                },"json");


            });


        });
```

The last one is isle.php

```php
<?php 



    $data=$_POST["data"];

    $gonderilecek=[
        "email_adres"=>$data["email"],
        "sifre"=>$data["password"],
        "mesaj"=>"mesajımız burada"
    ];


    echo json_encode($gonderilecek);
```

I could not solve the problem any one can help me

Comment: The error means it could not find the server on where its trying to connect to. Can you provide the full path. If they on the same machine http://localhost:3000. I think its trying on port 80 but your server is running on 3000

Comment: yep xampp using 80 port and , created 3000 port. i tried ```var socket = io('http:// localhost:3000);``` but now working